# Android webView ChromeClient onProgress

Tags: android

How to get resource url while loading a web page on the 
onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) callback ? i need it here 
because when loading from cache the onloadresource not being called on an already cached resource. thx

Answer (score 0):

When you use `WebChromeClient` you can override `onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)` this method for your purpose some thing like this will do the job.

```
yourWebViewObject.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
        {
            currentActivity.setTitle("Loading...");
            currentActivity.setProgress(progress * 100);

            if(progress == 100)
                currentActivity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        }
});
```

And for sample program you can use [Using Android’s WebView, WebChromeClient and WebViewClient to load a webpage and display the progress](http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=1331).

Comment: thx but can i get the resource URL corresponding to progress ?

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet may be helpful for showing intermediate progress:

```
 Button btnLoad = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_load);
     btnLoad.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             EditText etUrl = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_url);
              mWvUrl.loadUrl(etUrl.getText().toString());
              activity.setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
        }
    });

     mWvUrl.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

                /** This prevents the loading of pages in system browser */
                return false;
            }

            /** Callback method, executed when the page is completely loaded */
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                 super.onPageFinished(view, url);

                 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                                "Page loaded Completely",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                /** Hiding Indeterminate Progress Bar in the title bar*/
                activity.setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);

            }

        });
```

Comment: thx all. but i only need the resource URL to put into the progress dialog message like this: "resource URL"+ url + "progress in %" + progress